# Como puedo pasar consulta sql a eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

```
$sql = "select comunidades.name, comunidad_id, sum(total_necesidades) as necesidades, sum(total_problematicas) as problematicas, sum(total_emprendimientos) as emprendimientos
        from (
            select comunidades.name, comunidad_id, count(*) as total_necesidades, 0 as total_problematicas, 0 as total_emprendimientos
            from solicitudes
            JOIN comunidades on comunidades.id = comunidad_id
            where tipo_solicitud_id = 1
            group by comunidad_id
            union
            select comunidades.name, comunidad_id, 0 as total_necesidades, count(*) as total_problematicas, 0 as total_emprendimientos
            from solicitudes
            JOIN comunidades on comunidades.id = comunidad_id
            where tipo_solicitud_id = 2
            group by comunidad_id
            union
            select comunidades.name, comunidad_id, 0 as total_necesidades, 0 as total_problematicas, count(*) as total_emprendimientos
            from solicitudes
            JOIN comunidades on comunidades.id = comunidad_id
            where tipo_solicitud_id = 3
            group by comunidad_id
        ) as result JOIN comunidades on comunidades.id = comunidad_id ORDER BY comunidades.name";

        $reportes = DB::select($sql);
```

Comment: no se si eloquent lo tiene, pero doctrine no incluye el union en su sistema de QueryBuilder... asi que lo veo un poco dificil

Comment: ¿Qué problemas tuviste para convertir la consulta? Además, dale formato a tu código agregando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo.

Comment: quiero poder  filtrar por rangos de fechas

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega aquello que hayas intentado, de ese modo la pregunta se puede sujetar a [ask] y evitar su cierre

Answer (score -1):

Laravel cuenta con una opción para entregar consultas sql directamente, para ello te dejo la documentación y que puedas ver los ejemplos. La utilidad se llama expresiones RAW, si quieres encontrar más información puedes buscar en google ese término añadiendo RAW Queries Laravel.

Te dejo en enlace para que te ayude en lo que buscas [Expresiones RAW Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Eso no solucionaria la pregunta. Quiere pasar dicha consulta SQL a QueryBuilder. No obstante, seria una solución que debería plantearse.

Comment: Si funciona, lo que yo veo en el codigo que quiere pasar una instruccion sql completa en string a eloquent. Para ello deberia ejecutar DB::raw($sql). Esto ejecuta la consulta.

Comment: He cambiado la logica para no usar esa consulta.